# How do I log out of arqade?

Tags: support

Sometimes I am on my friends computer and i go to to this site, and it automatically goes on his profile. i look around a lot and can't find a log off place. How do I do this?

Answer (score 8):

I will be the somebody:

[image: In the dropdown menu there is a logout-button]

As pointed out by LessPop_MoreFizz [diamond] in the comments, there is a log-out button in the dropdown menu in the top right.